# ViewPager displays the same ListFragments for all pages

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-listfragment

I'm trying to use a ListFragment with a ViewPager using the FragmentPagerAdapter. The pager consists of two instances of the ListFragment. The ViewPager control works and allows me to swipe between the fragments however the same ListFragment appears in both pages. It seems that getItem() method of the ViewPager creates two different instances of the ListFragment but it displays only the second instance of it for both pages. Here is a code:

```
// FragmentPagerAdapter
private static class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {      
    public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm)   {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {
        Log.i("Page: ", index + "");
        return PageFragment.newInstance(pages.get(index));
        // pages is an ArrayList<ArrayList<Restaurant>> pages
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return numberOfPages;
    }
}


// ListFragment
public class PageFragment extends ListFragment {

    private static ArrayList<Restaurant> restaurantsList;

    public static PageFragment newInstance(ArrayList<Restaurant> restaurantsList) {
        PageFragment pageFragment = new PageFragment();
        pageFragment.setRestaurantsList(restaurantsList);
        return pageFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)   {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);      
    setListAdapter(new RestaurantArrayAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(), getRestaurantsList()) );
    return view;
    }


    private void setRestaurantsList(ArrayList<Restaurant> list)
    {
        restaurantsList = list;
    }

    private ArrayList<Restaurant> getRestaurantsList()
    {
        return this.restaurantsList;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well mate,
The problem is you've declared you array member as "Static",

`private static ArrayList<Restaurant> restaurantsList;`

Lose the static and you should be fine.

Comment: I would also recommend you saving the Array in the fragment as an "Argument" (setArguments() & getArguments) so it could be automatically recovered when the activity/fragment being re-created. (saves you code in the "onSavedInstance" method)

Comment: Good catch! Thanks it works as suppose to work. Regarding the setArguments() method: It accepts a Bundle argument and as you can see I'm using ArrayList of the custom object therefore I cannot pass it to the Bundle.

Comment: @MarcinS. You can put an arrayList in a Bundle (as it implements Serializable already). But as you wish :) good luck

Comment: I can place it into the Bundle as a Serializable. How can I easily deserialize it then?